# object definition in java within a special condition

Tags: java, oop, jsp, class, jakarta-ee

I want to use the lang variable in my code, and give the value in the `if` command.
Is the below code possible in .jsp page ?

```
<%
  String language = "EN";
  EN lang;
  if (language.equals("EN")){
    lang = new EN();
  }
  else if (language.equals("FR")){
    lang = new FR();
  }
%>
// html ...
<% out.print(lang.variable1); %>
```

i got this error :

```
incompatible types; found: mypackage.FR, required: mypackage.EN
```

code please ?

Comment: EN is the English resource bundle class ?! and FR is france ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
interface Lang {

}

class EN implements Lang {

}

class FR implements Lang {

}

<%
  String language = "EN";
  Lang lang;
  if (language.equals("EN")){
    lang = new EN();
  }
  else if (language.equals("FR")){
    lang = new FR();
  }
%>
```

Comment: how can i access the variables inside the EN or FR class ?

Comment: your another question has my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759950/professional-usage-of-abstract-class-for-translation/3760265#3760265

Answer (score 2):

Are classes `EN` and `FR` derived from a common interface or abstract class? If yes, you can change `EN lang;` to `<abstractClass> lang;`. If not, you can start thinking of refactoring your class. An ugly solution would be to use `Object lang;`

Comment: no they are a class in a package. u mean that i must define EN and FR as a interface or abstract? can u help me with code pleas ?

Comment: how can i access the variables inside the EN or FR class. Jaydeep code gives back the interface variables value.

Answer (score 1):

> lang = new FR();

You are assigning an object of type FR to lang which is of type EN and is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `lang` as `EN`, declare it as an instance of the superclass of `EN` and `FR` (perhaps `Lang` ?)