# professional usage of abstract class for translation

Tags: java, oop, class, jakarta-ee, abstract-class

the code below is not giving me the answer i want, i don't know where is the problem?
FR is the translation of EN (exactly like .properties file)
i want to read the translation from the FR.java file if 
i want to reach the hello variable of fr.java or en.java from the index.jsp page. but code i wrote gives me the value from Lang.java

```
String language = "FR";
```

the condition is in the .jsp file
jdk 1.4 gives me this error :Error(23,23): variable lang might not have been initialized

any body can help, code pleas?

file name Lang.java

```
package mypackage;

abstract public class Lang {
  public String hello= "home page";
}
```

filename EN.java

```
package mypackage;

public class EN extends Lang {
  public String hello = "hello";
}
```

filename FR.java

```
package mypackage;

public class FR extends Lang {
  public String hello = "bonjour";
}
```

file name : index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ page import="mypackage.Lang" %>
<%@ page import="mypackage.FR" %>
<%@ page import="mypackage.EN" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <title>language</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%
      String language = "EN";
      Lang lang;
      if (language.equals("EN")){
        lang = new EN();
        }
      else if (language.equals("FR")){
        lang = new FR();
      }
    %>
    <%
      out.print(lang.hello);
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if lanuage="EN" the output should be "hello". else if if lanuage="FR" the output should be "bonjour".

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
      String language = "EN";
      Lang lang;
      if (language.equals("EN")){
        lang = new EN();
        }
      else if (language.equals("FR")){
        lang = new FR();
      }
    %>
```

Here it can be the case where language stays un initialized so you need to initialize it

say

```
Lang lang = null;//or any default value
```

And to initialize local variable is compulsary

I don't understand the importance of this condition here you are assigning `"EN"` to language then what is the need of condition?

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition as follows:

```
if (language.equals("FR")){
    lang = new FR();
}
// add more languages here
// example:
// else if (language.equals("DE")) {
//     lang = new DE();
// }
else {
    lang = new EN();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not cater with the case where `language` is neither "EN" nor "FR". Pick a default language so that the `lang` variable is always initialised:

```
Lang lang;
if (language.equals("EN")){
    lang = new EN();
}
else // default case
    lang = new FR();
}
```

In addition, instead of declaring one attribute for each string that needs to be translated (e.g. `String home`) consider declaring a method that will take a "key" as a parameter, and return the corresponding translation for that key. For example, in your JSP you could use something like this:

```
out.print(lang.getString("home"));
```

Then have all your `Lang` subclasses return the proper, translated value for each key.

You might also want to have a look at [ResourceBundles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Comment: i want to reach the hello variable of fr.java or en.java from the index.jsp page. but code i wrote gives me the value from Lang.java.

Comment: The code you posted is accessing the `home` variable, not the `hello` variable. The `home` variable only seems to be defined in Lang.java, not in EN.java or FR.java.

Comment: sorry men,it was my mistake in the question, i edited the code. pleas check it again.

Comment: Class variables cannot be overriden in subclasses. You can override class methods, but only "hide" class variables. Instead, consider my suggestion of declaring a `getString` method in class `Lang`, then overriding this method in subclasses to return the proper translation for each key.

Answer (score 0):

If `language` is not equals to `EN` or `FR` then `Lang lang` will not be initialized. Set it explicitly to `new EN()` before the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for the lang variable:

```
Lang lang = new EN();
 if (language.equals("EN")){
     lang = new EN();
 }
 else if (language.equals("FR")){
    lang = new FR();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to print hello variable, declare that variable in abstract Lang class and initialize in concrete classes.

```
package mypackage;

abstract public class Lang {
  public String hello= "home page";
}
```

filename EN.java

```
package mypackage;

public class EN extends Lang {
   {
      hello = "hello";
   }
}
```

filename FR.java

```
package mypackage;

public class FR extends Lang {
     {
      hello = "bonjour";
   }
}
```